# fetch json value using Object.values in node js / Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch data from the JSON object by using Object.values

so my JSON looks like this

```js
const jsonValue=
[
 { 
  files:{
   title:{
   "en": "test"
   }
   ,
   description:{
    "en": "dummy description"
   }
  }
 },
 { 
  files:{
   title:{
   "eu": "without description"
   }
  }
 },
];

jsonValue.map((data)=>{
 const des =Object.values(Object.values(data)[0]?.description)?? "";
 console.log(...des)
})
```

I am trying to fetch the description value and if the description key is not present then it should return a blank space
I am using Object.values because `en`, and `eu` values get changed every time so to overcome this I am using Object.values

but it showing me an error cannot convert undefined.

My expected output is I want to fetch the description value if it presents inside the JSON and return a blank space if it is not present in JSON

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: [There's no JSON in your code](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is almost correct and I just did a small modification at the end to make it work as per the requirement.

This is how it works

1. First we will check if description itself is present and retrieve its key or default it to empty string
2. Then we will check if key is not empty string and then retrieve the value using the key.
3. Display the required result.

I just added a bit more console logs to show how each step behaves and these are not needed as part of solution.

Like VLAZ suggested it is always handy to use browser debugger tools to see the failed statements.

```js
const jsonValue=
[
 { 
  files:{
   title:{
   "en": "test"
   }
   ,
   description:{
    "en": "dummy description"
   }
  }
 },
 { 
  files:{
   title:{
   "eu": "without description"
   }
  }
 },
];

jsonValue.map((data)=>{
 console.log(Object.values(data)[0]?.description);
 const desKey = Object.values(data)[0]?.description ?? "";
 if(desKey !== ""){
  console.log(Object.values(desKey));
  const des = Object.values(desKey);
  console.log(...des)
 }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, when

```
const descriptions = jsonValue.map(value => 
  value.files.description ? 
    value.files.description[Object.keys(value.files.title)[0]] : 
    ''
)
console.log(descriptions)
```

will print `["dummy description", ""]` and should do the trock

Comment: What is the advantage of `value.files.description[Object.keys(value.files.title)[0]]` over `Object.values(value.files.description)[0]`? And why use The key from `value.files.title` rather than the one from `.description`?